# The arguments type and the return type in specific methods of MathNet.Numerics

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics, math.net

C# is a strongly-typed language, when I use MathNet.Numerics in C#, this put me to trouble.

for example:

when I call the `PointwiseMultiply()` method, the former matrix and the latter one must be the same type. That means I must convert a `Matrix<float>` into a `Matrix<Complex32>`, when it pointwise multiplies with a `Matrix<Complex32>` of the same dimension.

But we don't need to do that in MATLAB, so I'm wondering is there any better practice?

Excuse me for my simple question. :-)

Comment: If mathdotnet does not provide this you could create your own `PointwiseMultiply` that handles different `Matrix<T>` types and you could also create your own conversions between different `Matrix<T>` types. For practical purposes do this for the most commonly used types in your project (e.g. `Matrix<float>` and `Matrix<Complex32>` that you mentioned).

Comment: What don't you need to do? The conversion? And what do you mean by a better practice?

Comment: Yeap, in MATLAB, we don't need to do the conversion and we can use `.*` directly between a matrix of complex and a matrix of float. I hope the MathNet.Numerics will include this feature in the future. This is the "better practice" which I metioned. @mok

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I have to do it myself. @GDS